# Validation fluctuating on keras training

Tags: keras, training

My model is showing a very large variation in validation.
In generating the model used, 25% of the data as a test and 75% as a validation. The data was also divided.

Is there a way to reduce / eliminate this variation?

[image: 50 epoch]

[image: 500 Epoch]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the distribution of the validation data is not similar to the training data, and therefore the training signal does not lead the model to perform well on the validation data.

The key point here is therefore: how did you split the data into training and validation?

Comment: I divided the data set into 25% for testing and 75% for validation.
I am training an image classifier that has 3 classes (fire, smoke and other).

Comment: Did you shuffle the data before splitting it?

Comment: Yes, this is my code for splitting (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
 test_size=0.25, stratify=labels, random_state=42).

Comment: Is this behavior reproducible if you split again and re-train?

Comment: Yes, this happens every time I train the model.

 I cleaned the dataset and changed the learning rate, the variation improved a lot, now it oscillates very close to the loss. But still has an 'abnormal' oscillation

Comment: Do you have dropout, batch normalization, or any other element that changes the behavior of the network between training and evaluation modes?